# Cancellation token in "Task Run(Action action, CancellationToken cancellationToken)", what for?

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, async-await

My question is about [Task.Run(Action, CancellationToken)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160373.aspx), why there is `CancellationToken` when there is no explicit access to it from `Action` delegate?

I mean, I could still use it implicitly as part of delegate's captured context:

```
Task DoWorkAsync(CancellationToken ct)
{
    return Task.Run(() => 
    {
        while (moreWork) 
        {
           // do work
           ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        } 
    } 
}
```

In this case, why would I need to pass `ct` as second argument to `Run`? What am I missing?

Comment: Thanks @svick, it indeed makes sense, if `ct` is cancelled, `Action` should never be executed.

Comment: Yeah, assuming it didn't start executing already.